# Why did Benny question Quaid's decision to go to the Last Resort?

Tags: plot-explanation, total-recall

Just before Quaid enters the brothel Last Resort, Benny tries to talk him out of it by mentioning another place where "the girls are cleaner, the liquor ain't watered down".

However later on it's revealed that Benny, working for Cohagen all along, was sent to make sure Quaid finds and leads Cohagen's forces to Quato's rebels.

So why would he try to talk Quaid out of visiting the Last Resort which was presumably suspected of helping/sympathizing with the rebels? Wouldn't that defeat the purpose of his mission?

Comment: Mission complete: he wants to go to *The Last Resort*. They could definitely stop at the place he gets **kick backs** from first though, undoubtedly a part of *his* double dipping plan from the beginning. He's not just doing this for money. He's doing it for a shit load of money. First and foremost he's a cabbie. They already paid him for that other crap, and Quaid seems hellbent on going there anyway. Why not literally go fck around at some other place that's nicer first? He knows he's not there to get laid; you sure you don't want to go get laid first? Because after this his contract's over.

Comment: @Mazura - I'm sure that really ought to be an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Benny needs to:

1. Know for sure that Quaid is headed to Last Resort *for his mission* and not to have a good time.
2. Earn his trust, so he plays a friendly, talkative and helpful cab driver.

Suggesting to go to a better place than Last Resort achieves both the above.